# How to call a bash script from another script?

Tags: bash

I know there is many similar questions but I was not able to find an answer for mine:

I have couple of if and checking to get to this point of source script to call another script

```
source ./call.sh
```

And in destination script I want to get user name from user:

```
#!/bin/bash
passDir="/etc/passwd"
while true
    do
        #propmt for username
        read -p "Enter username : " username
        egrep "^$username" $passDir >/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "$username exists!"

        else
            userName=$username
            break
        fi
    done
```

But it doesn't wait for me to enter anything. It goes inside a loop and print exist unless I press Ctrl+C I appreciate if anyone can give me suggestion how to do it. In my destination script I have dozen of other prompts to get input from the user When I run destination script alone it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a extra script and call with `source command` and interactive with your script, You have to use `expect interpreter` such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect 
send 'username\r'
```

Sure, you need to pass somthing to your script and use its `return status`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very mobtadi in bash script. So I need to create another script. So from source I call this script and this script call destination script. Could you please just write a very simple one so I can use it.